# How can I reset form after submit in reactjs hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

this is my first time using hooks  I don't know How can I clear input fields after submit, form.reset() doesn't work

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import....

export default function AddUser() {
  const URL = "http://localhost:3000/AddUser";
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    if (data) {
      axios.post(URL, data);
    }
form.reset()
  };
```

here is the return part

```
  return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} noValidate>
        <div className="container">
              <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" ref={register({required: true})}/> 

              <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" ref={register({ required: true })}/>:Male

              <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" ref={register({ required: true })}/:Female
            <button type="submit" className="btn "> add</button>
        </div>
      </form>
  );
}
```

thanks in advance

//////////

[image: here is the error when I use form.reset()]

Comment: can you share where do you call `form.reset( {} )` and what errors show if any ?

Comment: Yes , I call it in onSubmit fun ... I edit the question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to import `reset` from `useForm()` hook to be able to use it outside of your  tags.

so
`const { register, handleSubmit, errors, reset } = useForm();`

then on your submit function

```
const onSubmit = (data) => {
    if (data) {
      axios.post(URL, data);
    }
    reset({})
  };
```

Something along those lines should work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a default state to set when your click is handle, that way your component will reset on every submit. And yet, and if you wanna prevent default you must set `event.preventDefault();` inside the `onSubmit` function

```
import { useForm, useState } from "react-hook-form";
import....

export default function AddUser() {
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState({})

  const URL = "http://localhost:3000/AddUser";
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    if (data) {
      setFormState(data)
      axios.post(URL, formState);
    }
form.reset()[![enter image description here][1]][1]
  };
```

Comment: thanks a lot , it is helpful but the better way is to import reset from useForm as 
"mena happy" said